# Terminal password authentication on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

for execution, Sudo command requires a password. But how can I tackle that on eclipse?

```
public String getMACLinux(String ipaddress) throws IOException {

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process p1 = r.exec("sudo ifconfig en0 ether" + ipaddress);
try
{
    p1.waitFor();
}
catch(InterruptedException ii)
{
    return ii.toString();
}
```

--> Process p1 = r.exec("sudo ifconfig en0 ether" + ipaddress);

this line does not work properly whenever I use it on eclipse.

--> sudo ifconfig en0 ether 12:23:89:a3:ff
it works when I use directly on the terminal; after entering the password. 
can anyone tell how to use it on eclipse?

Comment: Why is the function named `getMACWindows`? `sudo` and `ifconfig` are unix commands.

Comment: You will need to put the password into `stdin` and use the `-S` flag with `sudo`.

Comment: I am not asking how to mask password I am asking how to execute "sudo ifconfig en0 ether 12:23:89:a3:ff" on eclipse because this requires a password authentication. How to tackle password authentication on eclipse? :)

Comment: I am working on all platform to change mac with one click. It works with windows only the problem with mac. This is the chunk of code I forget to change methode name.

Comment: Sudo creates a secure input when checking for a password. Because of this it is very difficult to use from a programming language. Thus they added the `-S` flag to allow for the password to be read in from stdin. This allows you to use it with pipes. If Runtime#exec() allows you to use pipes, you should use that, otherwise you will need to load the password into stdin some other way.